# Microsoft Band: Show notification on band from Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, microsoft-band

I am attempting to show an alert on the MS Band on receipt of a google cloud message with an Android Application. I am using Azure Notification Hubs to send and respond to messages. On receipt of the message I would like to send a notification to the band.

The issue I am getting at the moment is that when I check for the bands connection in the NotificationHandler the following exception is thrown:

> BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to bind to services

The code in question is as follows:

```
if (client == null) {
        BandInfo[] devices = BandClientManager.getInstance().getPairedBands();
        if (devices.length == 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Band isn't paired with your phone");
            return false;
        }
        client = BandClientManager.getInstance().create(ctx, devices[0]);
    } else if (ConnectionState.CONNECTED == client.getConnectionState()) {
        return true;
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Band is connecting...");
    return ConnectionState.CONNECTED == client.connect().await();
```

The exception is thrown when calling `client.connect().await()`

I assume that the Notification Handler is configured as a BroadcastReceiver beind the scenes and that by trying to interact with the Band I am breaking the rules of a BroadcastReceiver by binding to a service.

How should I handle this scenario? Surely this is a common scenario - mirroring a notification on the band as it is picked up by the application? The only way I and think to handle this is to create a new Intent Service to show the notification and start that from the BroadcastReciever, but this seems kinda clunky?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create an Intent Service which I fire up in the broadcast receiver to handle the sending of the message to the Band. This allows the receiver to respond and exit quickly and the band connection can happen in the service.

It's not really as clunky as I imagined.